# Controlling two ViewPager Together

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, android-scroll

I need to synchronize the two ViewPager together. The requirement is something like on scrolling the ViewPager-1 and the ViewPager-2 should also scroll by certain amount. The Image shown below will make you more clear with my question.

[image]

You can also help me with some tutorials link. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I think this is what you need:

```
        viewpager1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                viewpager2.onTouchEvent(event);
                return false;
            }
        });

        viewpager2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                viewpager1.onTouchEvent(event);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I have a same problem, but first I try to use fakeDragBy method, which is dead end. (if you have more than two pages)

Comment: Using this technique, I get a crash if you simultaneously touch both view pagers. I ended up using the approach here instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26513243/369480

Comment: I like this solution because it's making the `ViewPagerIndicator` more smooth with the two view pagers, but it has a bug when you use multi-touch as described in the previous comment which I couldn't do something to prevent, so I disabled the multi-touch by using `android:splitMotionEvents="false"` in the XML layout and it now works good!

Answer (score 2):

You can extend ViewPager in order to create a custom view and override onTouchEvent() in the following way:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

          if(mDependentView != null){
            mDependentView.onTouchEvent(event);
          }
          return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
```

Also create a setter inside your custom class in order to set the dependentView

```
public void setDependentView(View view){
   mDependentView = view;
}
```

Then you should set the second viewpager as dependent view of the first viewpager in your activity.