# Two ViewPagers in one activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have two questions about ViewPager.

I have in my activity 2 ViewPagers, one for each week (of date). For example, one for 14/9/14 - 20/9/14, and the the other one for the next week 21/9/14 - 27/9/14. When I slide the ViewPager to it's next one, it will change each on of the ViewPagers to the next week of itself (21/9/14 - 27/9/14, 28/9/14 - 4/10/14).

1. When I change the data f the second ViewPager and then slide the first ViewPager to it's next one (and this is the same week like the second view pager data that I changed), it won't show the changes that I made, unless I slide two more times and then return to the changed week (because of the memory of the ViewPager). I tried `mPager1.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);` , but it didn't helped. What can I do in order to solve that? [image]
2. I want that when I slide one of my ViewPagers, so the other one will animate itself exactly like my finger is sliding the other ViewPager. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: I cannot for the life of me understand any of the above...

Comment: first `mPager1.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);` never works because of UX, second please make your first question clearer.

Comment: @2Dee now it's better?

Answer (score 3):

I hope it helps:

> it won't show the changes that I made

use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after you have made changes.

> I want that when I slide one of my ViewPagers, so the other one will
>   animate itself exactly like my finger is sliding the other ViewPager.
>   Any ideas how to do that?

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager1= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager1);
    viewPager2= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager2);

    viewPager1.setAdapter(new MyAdapter1(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    viewPager2.setAdapter(new MyAdapter2(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    viewPager1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            viewPager2.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    });

    viewPager2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            viewPager1.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    });

    }
```

[image]

if you got

```
09-19 05:49:29.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1272): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
```

try:
in your layout file you must use `<package name of HackyViewPager.HackyViewPager` instead of `<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`

```
public class HackyViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public HackyViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }
    public HackyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        try {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

   }
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       try {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
     }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
     }

   }

}
```

Reference:

[Controlling two ViewPager Together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757859/controlling-two-viewpager-together)

Comment: Thank you very much! That really what I need!! 
Where to put the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` ? How can I know from the activity if the fragment changed?

Comment: `Where to put the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ?`  after you changed the data of the fragment. `How can I know from the activity if the fragment changed?` use callback method or use `getActivity().ihaveChanged();` that means you call a method from activity if it is not clear please ask it on SO with full description of your situation.

Comment: `09-19 05:49:29.313: E/AndroidRuntime(1272): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range`
That what happening when I use the `onTouch` method

Comment: i do not know whats going on there but please ask it with full logcat, i and others are ready to help you..

Comment: look at these links and if still you have a problem ask it on SO:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459196/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-pointerindex-out-of-range-exception-dispat and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919292/pointerindex-out-of-range-android-multitouch

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help! I fixed my first problem with the data refresh! About the second one- in the first link it says that there is a bug, and to fix that it says that I need to "create a custom view that extends ViewPager, override onTouchEvent and wrap the call to super.onTouchEvent in a try/catch.". How can I do that? And this solution will work always?

Comment: in your layout file you must use `<com.example.yarkon.Activity_Iyush$HackyViewPager` instead of `<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`

Comment: Well, thanks to the `try` and `catch` it's not crashing now... The problem is that the 2 `HackyViewPager` are not moving together (probably because it always get the `catch`...)

Comment: I changed my sample code with that HackyViewPager and it is working sorry i do not know what is your problem. if you want to make sure tell me your email so you can see it.