# How to combine view pager transformations

Tags: android

Is there any way to combine multiple transformations into just one custom transformation that can be applied to a view pager?

For example, I have this view pager layout with two image views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayoutLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"/>

</RelativeLayoutLayout>
```

I want the first image view to transform according this tranformation

```
public class FadePageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {



        view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

        if(position <= -1.0F || position >= 1.0F) {
            view.setAlpha(0.0F);
        } else if( position == 0.0F ) {
            view.setAlpha(1.0F);
        } else {
            // position is between -1.0F & 0.0F OR 0.0F & 1.0F
            view.setAlpha(1.0F - Math.abs(position));
        }
    }
}
```

And I want the second view to transform according some other custom transformation

```
public class CustomTranform implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

        //Some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method worked great for me. I just synced two pagers together.

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        viewPager2.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
});

viewPager2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        viewPager.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Credit goes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757859/controlling-two-viewpager-together).