# How to synchronize two view pagers

Tags: android

I want to synchronize touch events between two view pagers. I've tried this, but I observe no effect.

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        viewPager.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
});

viewPager2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        viewPager2.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I'm just an idiot. This method works great! No time lag or anything. I just just got my pager defined the wrong way around!

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        viewPager2.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
});

viewPager2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        viewPager.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Credit goes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757859/controlling-two-viewpager-together).